# moving files to folders based on extension

Tags: file, batch-file, directory

Finally I got to move files with different extensions into folders according to their extensions, but I cannot get rid of the "." preceding the created folders... Here's my batch file:

```
for %%i in (*) do mkdir "%%~xi" & move "%%i" "%%~xi"
```

Please help me remove the dot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*) do (
    set ext=%%~xi
    set ext=!ext:~1!
    mkdir "!ext!" 
    move "%%i" "!ext!"
)
```

Comment: You should put quotes around your set statements, e.g. `set "x=!x:~1!"`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is just creating a folder names after the file extension. To remove the dot all you need to do is remove the first character.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*) do (   
   set "x=%%~xi"   
   set x=!x:~1,400!  
   mkdir "!x!"
   move "%%i" "!x!" 
)  
pause  `
```

If you by chance just want to rename the folders:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
   set x=%%D
   set x=!x:~1,100!
   set y=!x:~0,1!
   if "!y!"=="." (
        rename "%%D" "!x!"
  )
 )
pause
```

Comment: You should put quotes around your set statements, e.g. `set "x=!x:~1!"` and you can much easier use `!x:~1!` instead of `!x:~1,400!`